# Regarding files resulted in equating file properties in "ls" command

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, ls, file-attributes

I have a folder in which there are thousands of images. Of those thousand images, I want to bring together all those images whose “Last created” and “Last modified” properties are exactly same.
( In other words, I want to separate all the images I didn’t ever rename for example )

Is there a way to do this from terminal ?

these are the two commands that I want to concatenate
**ls -tU** lists file by creation date. (I'm on a mac)
**ls -lt** lists file by modified date

such that I want to
**"List files whose date created = date modified"**

Comment: Is the `U` / `tU` option a new one? Not here http://ss64.com/osx/ls.html (I'm not o'sex).

Comment: Does not look like OSX native find has a `printf` option. If suitable perhaps some extended version has. Then some thing like (here GNU find (linux) comparing access and mod time) `find . -name '*.jpg' -printf '%A+\0%T+\0%f\n' | awk -F '\0' '$1 == $2 {print $3}'` – linux does not have a `creation` time-stamp.

Comment: OXyS has `GetFileInfo` (http://ss64.com/osx/getfileinfo.html), but I do not have any box o test on so I do not know if it list both when using `GetFileInfo -d -m`

Comment: If none of the above works you might have to resort to scripting in e.g. Python where both creation and access time is accessible. Sure there are tools that can do it, but as I am, (not sure if I have mentioned it before; on a MaC), it becomes a bit cumbersome to test further.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use the `mdls` command. `mdls` lists the metadata attributes for a specified file. Here is a sample output for a .png file I have on my Desktop

```
$  mdls ~/Desktop/hipchat.png
_kMDItemOwnerUserID            = 205009058
_kTimeMachineIsCreationMarker  = 1
_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot    = 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot    = 2016-06-10 19:25:01 +0000
kMDItemBitsPerSample           = 32
kMDItemColorSpace              = "RGB"
kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2016-06-10 19:37:53 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2016-06-10 19:37:53 +0000
kMDItemContentType             = "public.png"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "public.png",
    "public.image",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded               = 2016-06-10 19:45:06 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName             = "hipchat.png"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = 2016-06-10 19:37:53 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = 2016-06-10 19:37:53 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                 = 0
kMDItemFSName                  = "hipchat.png"
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = 80
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = 205009058
kMDItemFSSize                  = 22994
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemHasAlphaChannel         = 0
kMDItemKind                    = "Portable Network Graphics image"
kMDItemLogicalSize             = 22994
kMDItemOrientation             = 0
kMDItemPhysicalSize            = 24576
kMDItemPixelCount              = 74520
kMDItemPixelHeight             = 81
kMDItemPixelWidth              = 920
kMDItemResolutionHeightDPI     = 0
kMDItemResolutionWidthDPI      = 0
```

You can then extract the info your looking for like so.

```
$  mdls ~/Desktop/hipchat.png |grep -e kMDItemContentCreationDate |awk '{print "Created on "$3" at "$4}'
Created on 2016-06-10 at 19:37:53

$  mdls ~/Desktop/hipchat\ poll.png |grep -e kMDItemContentModificationDate |awk '{print "Modified on "$3" at "$4}'
Modified on 2016-06-10 at 19:37:53
```